# Downgrade OpenCV using HomeBrew when brew versions is deleted

Tags: opencv, version, homebrew

I am using the latest version (1.8.2) of homebrew and I am trying to downgrade opencv 3.4.3 to 3.4.0.

I followed this answer [homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763) However, the problem is that even after I `brew tap homebrew/boneyard`, `brew versions opencv` still does not work.

How can I make 'brew versions' work for homebrew 1.8.2?

If that does not work, can I manually download and set up opencv 3.4.0 to homebrew?

Comment: The tap `homebrew/boneyard` is deprecated and contains no more formulas. You have to follow the point 3 of the answer you mention.

Comment: Please don’t use the [tag:brew] tag; it has nothing to do with Homebrew.